# Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove $\cosh(x) \ge 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}$ in the interval $[0,x]$, given $\sinh(x) \ge x$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove $\cosh(x) \ge 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}$ in the interval $[0,x]$, given $\sinh(x) \ge x$ for all $x \gt 0$.

I tried using $f(x) = \cosh(x)$, but to no avail. All help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you copied this correctly. It seems that the variable $x$ is used in two different meanings in: *prove $\cosh(x) \ge 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}$ in the interval $[0,x]$.* (This makes the question unclear. Of course, I might have misunderstood something.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak http://puu.sh/3eJMs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the function $f(x)=\cosh (x)-1-\frac{x^2}2$.

You clearly have $f(0)=0$. Can you show $f'(x)\ge0$. If you use these facts and [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $\cosh (x) \leq 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}$, within that interval and let $f(x) = \cosh (x)$. Then, the mean value theorem tells us that there exists an $x_0 \in [0,x]$ such that

$$f'(x_0) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}.$$

If $f(x) = \cosh (x) \implies f'(x) = \sinh (x)$. From the constraint given, we know that $\sinh (x_0) \geq x_0$. Now, let's work out the RHS of the MVT equality:

$$1) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,f(x) = \cosh (x) = \cosh (x)$$
$$2) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, f(0) = \cosh (0) = 1$$
$$3) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \, x - 0 = x.$$

Subbing this all in, we get:

$$\sinh (x_0) = \frac{\cosh (x) - 1}{x}.$$

As $\sinh (x_0) \geq x_0$ we get

$$x_0 \leq \frac{\cosh (x) - 1}{x}$$
$$x \cdot x_0 \leq \cosh (x) - 1$$
$$\implies \cosh(x) \geq 1 + x \cdot x_0.$$

We know that $x_o \leq x$ and so, the biggest value this $x_0$ can possible take is $x$, putting this in gives us

$$\cosh (x) \leq 1 + x \cdot x = 1  +x^2$$

which is a contradiction as we said that $\cosh (x) \leq 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} < 1 + x^2$, as $x > 0$.

Comment: $\sinh(x)\geq x$ implies $\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{x}\geq x$

Comment: @Amr Oh yeah, sorry, typo.

Comment: It seems to me that your argument can be used to show that $\cosh(x)\geq 1+x^2$ (a better lower bound)

Comment: @Amr As opposed to $\geq 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}$? So it doesn't answer this question properly?

Comment: OK . There is a mistake

Comment: Why does $f'(x_0)=sinh(x) $?

Comment: $f'(x_0)=\sinh(x_0)$ and not $\sinh(x)$

Comment: Still. Now $x_0\leq sinh(x_0)$

Comment: I tried to skip a step because it was going to be greater than or equal to $x$ for all $x$ so I didn't bother putting in the specific point, but yeah, that's not good practice.

Comment: Ahhh, ok!! I get what I've done wrong. Let me try and fix it quickly

Comment: fact: $\cosh(0.1)<1+(0.1)^2$

Comment: Hi Kaish. I still think that the proof is incorrect

Comment: @Amr Oh, so everything I've done is wrong? I should just delete it then right?

Comment: Unless you see a way of fixing it. I don't see a way

Comment: @Amr How is it wrong? If I knew that then maybe I could try and fix it?

Comment: Everything is fine until the line that says $\sinh(x_0)=\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{x}$

Comment: You should ve stated afterwards $x_0\leq \sinh(x_0)=\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{x}$ and not $x\leq \sinh(x)=\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{x}$

Comment: @Amr Then I get $\cosh (x) \geq 1 + x \cdot x_0$ and then as $x_0 \leq x$ this is $\leq 1 + x^2$ (taking the most extreme value of $x_0$, yeah?

Comment: This will not work. Yo reached $\cosh(x)\geq 1+x_0x$. But this does not imply that $\cosh(x)\geq 1+x^2$.